# Frequent logouts in ASP.NET Core app hosted on Google Cloud Run

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-identity, google-cloud-run

I have developed an application using ASP.Net Core Razor Pages and I have pretty big problem with frequent user logouts. The application is using default ASP Core Identity service. Logouts occur from time to time when navigating between random pages. Until I hosted this app on App Engine Flex everything was all right but however, for various reasons I had to change the hosting environment.
Maybe anyone has any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: is it App Engine Flex or Cloud Run? What other environments have you tried? Locally, in a GCE instance? In another provider's service? Can you give more details about your application, such as, how does the application save the Identity data, in a Cloud SQL SQL Server instance, or somewhere else? Have you configured  "options.ExpireTimeSpan"? If so, how?

Comment: Cloud Run can provide multiple, stateless instances to respond to requests. How are you maintaining user session state across HTTP requests?

Comment: The app is hosted on Cloud Run. I think locally I don't see such a effect. Identity is a default ASP.NET Core module, so it is stored in DB. The user session is maintained using cookies and I have tried few thinks but the logouts still occur. It is strange, because when application want me to login again, it is enough just to refresh the page and the session is restored and I am logged in. I have noticed that, when this problem occur, there is a massage in logs: `Container Sandbox: Unsupported syscall membarrier(0x0,0x0,0x1f,0x0,0xd,0x1)`

Comment: There is a github thread where this issue is discussed, it might help your issue  https://github.com/google/gvisor/issues/267#issuecomment-553444294